# How to open file with default application from command line?

Tags: command-line

In Nautilus, when you double click a file, it will open it with the default application associated with the file's extension. For instance, .html files will open in a web browser and .pdf will be opened with Document Viewer. Is there a way to reproduce the same behavior from within the command line (i.e. `open path/filename`)? I'm asking because I like to browse my file-system from the command line but sometimes don't remember which app. opens what.

Comment: There is a similar question regarding launching default browser from the command line: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8252/how-to-launch-default-web-browser-from-the-terminal

Comment: That's a brilliant question indeed! In almost 4 years of my `bash`ing I hadn't thought about it :P

Answer (score 319, accepted):

I think [**`xdg-open`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xdg-open.1) is the command you are looking for.

```
NAME
       xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application

SYNOPSIS
       xdg-open {file | URL}

       xdg-open {--help | --manual | --version}

DESCRIPTION
       xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
       URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
       browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred
       application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http
       and https URLs.
```

eg: `xdg-open index.php`

This will open index.php in gedit(if you are using gnome).

If you want to open a url in browser

```
xdg-open http://google.com
```

this will open google.com in your default browser.

---

`xdg-open` is a wrapper script - it will use the desktop environment's tool (`gio open`, `gvfs-open`, `kde-open`, `gnome-open`, `dde-open`, `exo-open`, and a host of other such tools). It is also installed by default, and very likely to work on past, current and future versions (on the other hand, `gvfs-open` and `gnome-open` have been deprecated, and may be unavailable in future releases).

Comment: On Gnome: `gnome-open` and on KDE: `kde-open` works.

Comment: `xde-open` worked on xfce as well.

Comment: easy way to shorten this command is to use an alias. `alias o='xdg-open'`. Put this inside your `.bash_aliases` file to make the alias load on startup each time. `nano ~/.bash_aliases` and then paste inside `nano` using `CTRL+SHIFT+V`.

Comment: The command `browse` seems to do the same (seen on Ubuntu 19.04).

Comment: For other novices like me, `xdg` stands for [*X (cross) Dekstop Group*](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/jiizsm/what_does_xdg_mean/)

Answer (score 52):

`xdg-open` and `gnome-open`

`xdg-open` is the most universal way (work also on KDE)

Comment: for ubuntu 10.04 it seems not to be granted that gnome-open is installed (Command 'gnome-open' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install libgnome2-bin). xdg-open was installed (at least on my machine :) )

Answer (score 20):

If you want to:

- make an alias for this command (e.g. `open`)
- hide output from the command
- continue using this terminal after

You can use this [.bashrc function](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-functions):

```sh
function open () {
  xdg-open "$@">/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Comment: Alternative is a simpler version that does not hide output or move to background: `alias o='xdg-open`.

Comment: I would at least call the function "myopen" or something because it may conflict with /bin/open. Btw this is a potential trap for any alias (even "myopen" might already exist).