# How to open a specific application like macOS `open -a`?

Tags: command-line

On macOS in the default Terminal running `bash`, I can type:

```
open -a Firefox http://www.wikipedia.org
```

to open a URL with Firefox, or another browser. It also works to launch a program, e.g. `open -a maps`, and to open a file in the default program, e.g. `open file.pdf`.

How can I do the same on Ubuntu in the default GNOME Terminal also running `bash`? I know that I can open a file or URL with `xdg-open /path/to/file`, and I can open the default browser with `sensible-browser`. Does Ubuntu have a general command to open files, applications, or files in specific applications?

I am running `bash` on both machines, `3.2.57(1)-release` on macOS and `4.4.19(1)-release` on Ubuntu.

Comment: I've never used a Mac, so can you tell me why you'd use `open -a Firefox http://www.wikipedia.org`? Can't you do `firefox http://www.wikipedia.org`? It seems like a useless feature of `open`, when opening programs is the very point of `bash`.

Comment: Bash on macOS works differently, e.g. your command gives the error `bash: firefox: command not found`. Same error with `Firefox` as program name.

Comment: `bash` works exactly the same; it's Firefox that is installed differently than it is on Ubuntu. On macOS, you could, for instance, run `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin` from the command line. `Firefox.app` is a special kind of folder that contains not just the executable, but files that in Linux might be scattered about in various `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/lib`, `/etc`, etc. directories. The Finder knows how to run the actual application when you, for instance, double-click on `Firefox.app`. `open` is a way to "run" the special folder from the command line.

Comment: It's not that `bash` works differently: firefox is installed as an OS X application (`Firefox.app`) and is not on the regular PATH. Another reason to use `open -a` is that it properly backgrounds the application it launches, instead of waiting on it until it exits.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/15356 `&`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specifically use your desired program's name (if it's able to be used as a command line tool).

For example, urls:

```
firefox duckduckgo.com
chromium-browser askubuntu.com
```

PDF:

```
evince foo.pdf
okular bar.pdf
```

Images:

```
gpicview foo.png
feh bar.jpeg
```

Texts:

```
gedit foo.txt
mousepad /etc/config
leafpad bar.xml
```

Video/Music:

```
mpv  foo.mp3
vlc  bar.mp4
```

---

If you want the program to be run detached from the terminal then this is the way that I prefer doing it:

```
nohup program args &
```

For example:

```
nohup firefox askubuntu.com &
```

Remember that you can always redirect the outputs as usual, e.g. :

```
nohup firefox duckduckgo.com &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: `eog picture.jpg` for images too if you have gnome-desktop installed :)

Comment: @Videonauth Yeah, or any other kind of tools ;)

Comment: This is a somewhat acceptable answer but it just works around the question, doesn't it? Afaik Ubuntu doesn't have an equivalent to macOS' `open`.

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier I don't get the point of calling `open` to call another program. Why not just call the other program directly? What usefulness does `open` add? This answer reflects the natural thing to do to open specific applications.

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier I see your point, but the answer does what I wanted to do, so I accepted it.

Comment: @mmorin you're the boss. :)

Comment: @JoL obviously this is the most Ubuntu-like answer and that's fine - however having a single command that can open anything as if you were just double-clicking the file in a file explorer can prove really useful too.

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier I agree, and `open` on macOS works both for opening files and folders in the default application and in specific applications. It seems the original `bash` went on a different path with `xdg-open` for files and the application names for the rest.

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier https://askubuntu.com/a/15356 `&`

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier The equivalent to double-clicking is `xdg-open`. With `xdg-open` you don't specify a program name, just as you don't when double-clicking.

Comment: For more thorough ways of launching a GUI app from the command line, see this question: [How to cleanly launch a GUI app via the Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10547/301745) My preferred method is `($app $arguments &>/dev/null &)`.

Comment: Another thing that is different about `open` in MacOS is that it launches the application detached from the console it's run from, i.e. if the console closes, the app will stay on. On Ubuntu one needs to use the `nohup` command to get the same behaviour. (since prefixing each command with nohup and redirecting output for each command you run gets tiring, it may make more sense to define a custom shortcut)

Comment: @undercat Personally I use a function: `abandon()("$@" &>/dev/null &)`, then I can use it like `abandon firefox http://example.org`.

Answer (score 2):

As [indicated in a response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080846/how-to-open-a-specific-application-like-macos-open-a/1080849#comment1776476_1080849) to the accepted anwser, the equivalent to the `open` command from macOS in Linux is [xdg-open](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open):

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>   URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>   browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the
>   preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file,
>   ftp, http and https URLs.

When compared to the macOS `open`, the main difference is that here you can't specify an specific application to use from the command line. For that, you can refer to the accepted answer, as the problem is kind of pointless in Linux because applications are normally available in your PATH already.