# Which of all console web browsers is the most practical?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browse internet inside terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15988/browse-internet-inside-terminal)

There are a lot of console browsers, `links2`, `Lynx`, `w3m` and `Elinks` (I only know these). I want to know which one of all console browsers are most practical to browse with if you are logged into a server via ssh and have to browse the web.

I need a good console browser because I want to be able to connect to the server with any client that has ssh. I don't want to limit the question by specifying on a specific server or client.

- no GUI (it's a server via ssh I mean come on!)
- send emails with files
- be able to log into gmail and other "secure" sites.