# Should I install exo-utils to search Google from the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I entered this command on my terminal:

```
google query to search
```

and it responded by saying that the program exo-utils is missing on my computer. When I tried to install it, the response was

> WARNING:the packages could not be authenticated.

Can anyone tell me what `exo-utils` is?

Comment: The answers technically answer your question, but do you want is to search web from the terminal? In that case you can [`ddgr` for DuckDuckGo](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/duck-duck-go-terminal-app) (or `googler` if you don't care about privacy). BTW, to get more info about a package use `apt show packageName`.

Answer (score 2):

This package contains the `Xfce` settings plugin and the utility files for `libexo-0.3-0` which are:

- `exo-csource`
- `exo-desktop-item-edit`
- `exo-mount`
- `exo-open`
- `exo-preferred-applications`
- `exo-eject`
- `exo-unmount`

The discripton for `libexo` on [Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libexo-0.3-0) is

> libexo is a library for Xfce that contains a bunch of additional
>   widgets and a framework for editable toolbars (an improved version of
>   the framework present in GNOME), light-weight session management
>   support, functions to automatically synchronize object properties
>   (based on GObject Binding Properties) and several miscellaneous
>   utility and helper functions for application developers.
>
> While Xfce ships with quite a few libraries that are primarily
>   targeted at desktop development, libexo is targeted at application
>   development, with a focus on applications for Xfce.

As for `WARNING:the packages could not be authenticated` please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository) with a good answer

None of this really matters, you can't search Google like that.

The package `googlecl` allows some functionality in terminal but not search, only

`picasa`, `blogger`, `youtube`, `docs`, `contacts`, `calendar`, `finance` parameters.

To search online from a terminal please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15988/browse-internet-inside-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

I googled it and found:

`Exo-utils` are Utility files for `libexo`

The package contains the `Xfce` settings plugin and the utility files for
 `libexo` which vary slightly based on version.

Example install of the `exo-utils` package on Ubuntu systems with apt:

```
  sudo apt-get install exo-utils
```

Comment: The question was: can anyone tell me what "Exo-utils" is?

Comment: My answer was: Exo-utils are Utility files for libexo

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you but you are correct with this, the downvote is likely due to formatting, or copy/paste with out a source. -1 is not == wrong.

Comment: Don't forget to format code with {} option in the tool bar of the editor :)

Comment: re: exo-utils are utils for exo?  And pages are things in a book. A book is a thing full of pages. Google: tautological