# Can't open Chrome as default browser from terminal

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, browser, default-browser

I'm trying to use the answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/8252/453746), but all fail by either doing nothing, or giving me this error:

> Aborted (core dumped)

I'm on 14.04 Trusty Tahr using Google Chrome as my default browser - which is no doubt the problem somehow, because when I set Chromium as my default browser, then Chromium opens just fine. But what's the work around? Or how can I look at the "dumped core" to get more information?

Here's what I've tried:

```
jeff $ sensible-browser
Aborted (core dumped)
jeff $ sensible-browser http://example.org
Aborted (core dumped)
jeff $ x-www-browser http://example.org
Aborted (core dumped)
jeff $ gnome-open http://example.org
jeff $ xdg-open http://example.org
jeff $ xdg-open 'http://example.org' >/dev/null
```

Comment: Why not open chrome directly with `google-chrome http://example.org`?

Comment: @PranavMarathe Because I'm trying to open the "default" browser, regardless of what it is so that it's portable for my script to use on machines that don't necessarily have google chrome installed.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can try diagnosing the issue with strace : `strace sensible-browser`.

Comment: But does `google-chrome <url>` work for you? Just rule out that's not the thing that's crashing here.

Comment: @oli hmm, I'm not sure. That's a good question. Unfortunately, I no longer use chrome nor have it installed on any machine - I'm strictly chromium now.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that either the configuration (in ~/.config/chromium/ ) or the cache ( ~/.cache/chromium/ ) from your Chromium installation is confusing Google Chrome. Perhaps back up these directories, remove them and try starting Google Chrome again.

If this fails you could try with [strace](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace): `strace -f -v -s 1024 sensible-browser`. It will print a ton of information and if you are lucky the error (can't open a file, messed up permissions, etc) would be close to the bottom. You will need some basic knowledge of C though.

Looking at the "dumped core" requires advanced programming knowledge and access to the source code. If you haven't done that before I will advice you not to go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually installed chromium afterwards while trying to troubleshoot. You can see when I edited my question. I will take a look at strace tomorrow. Thanks again